# How to query SQLAlchemy to return a summed value of related records?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I am creating a small program that keeps track of what tasks users have performed. Each task has a value. If a user has performed a task, a new entry is made in a third table (called `Stripe`) that saves the user and the performed task.

My Models look like this:

```
class User(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'user'
    # ...
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    stripes = db.relationship(Stripe, backref=db.backref('related_user'), lazy='select')

class Task(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'task'
    # ...
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    value = db.Column(db.Integer, nullable=False)
    stripes = db.relationship(Stripe, backref=db.backref('related_task'), lazy='select')


class Stripe(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'stripe'
    # ...
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    task = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('task.id'), nullable=False)
    user = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('user.id'), nullable=False)
```

I have a problem to get the total (`sum`) of all `value` of all tasks a user has performed.
Expected output:

| User ID | Total stripe value | Additional user Columns |
| --- | --- | --- |
| User_1 | 3 | ... |
| User_2 | 10 | ... |
| User_3 | 0 | ... |

I've tried:

- Joining User and Stripe

  ```
       users = db.session.query(User).join(Stripe).all()
  ```

but this does not return any users that do not have stripes. I want it to return 0 then.

- querying stripes though user.

  ```
   users = User.query.all()
       for user in users:
           print(user.stripes) # returns list with stripes
           print(user.stripes.task) # returns error
  ```

Last statement returns `AttributeError: 'InstrumentedList' object has no attribute 'task'`. Why can't I access task in this way?

How can I query my models so that it returns the user table with an additional column `Total Stripes Value`? (the total value of all performed tasks for that user)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use [outer join](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/orm/query.html#sqlalchemy.orm.Query.outerjoin) to include rows that can't join because their is no matching record (ie. no stripes).  Join from users to stripes to tasks so that you can get the task value.  Use [`func.sum`](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/core/functions.html#sqlalchemy.sql.functions.sum) to add the values up.  Use [`func.coalesce`](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/core/functions.html#sqlalchemy.sql.functions.coalesce) to convert `NULL` to `0` for unmatched users, ie. users with no stripes.  You can find `LEFT OUTER JOIN`, `SUM` and `COALESCE` in the documentation of whichever underlying database you are using.

```py
q = session.query(User, func.coalesce(func.sum(Task.value), 0)).outerjoin(User.stripes).outerjoin(Stripe.related_task).group_by(User.id)
for user, value_total in q.all():
    print(user, value)
```

In order to reference the tasks from user you need to go through the stripes and use `related_task`, based on your backref, like this:

```py
tasks = [stripe.related_task for stripe in user.stripes]
```

Comment: Very nice! I totally forgot about the backref. Thank you!